# Hide soft navigation bar on WP8.1 using Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I have created an app with XDK using phonegap/cordova. It works perfectly on all devices I have tested from Iphone 4s,iphone 6 to Ipad and few Android devices. Somehow on Windows Phone 8.1 app opens fine and works fine, except if you have the soft navigation bar (the original navbar at the bottom of the screen on Lumia 735) open then part of the app (at the top) is missing.

Is there something to resize the app if navigation bar is open or closed? or to just hide navigation bar when app is open?

Hope for your help guys, googles everywhere I already could

Answer (score 0):

Specify Fullscreen mode in config.xml. Copy following entry in the www\config.xml which will disable the status bar for all platforms.

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help, I am also talking about "soft" navigation bar with back button etc on some WP8.1 phones.